# Create an empty object with a specific prototype

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I'm in the process of converting a classical OOP project to JS. Everything goes well and I just need to know if one of the methods I used has a shorthand/conventional way to achieve the same I did with it.

In my design I needs to create an empty object with a specific prototype. I used an empty dummy function as the `constructor`since I needed an empty object. I can't use `new Object()` since I need to attach a prototype before the creation.

Here is my code:

```
var baseObj = {name: '', id: 0}

function emptyObj () {
    //this is really a dummy
}

emptyObj.prototype = Object.create(baseObj);

myUser = new emptyObj();
```

Please note that **I have to follow this pattern** and my project works very well with it. I just want to know if there is a shorthand/conventional method to create an empty object with a prototype.

**Please stick to ES5.**

Comment: Shorthand to those 2 lines of code? Wrap them in a function and it will be one line of code.

Comment: `if (i==2) { foo = true};`  can be `foo = i ==2;` A short hand method for 2 lines of code. It's not about the number of lines. It is about the concept and the quality of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know if there is a shorthand/conventional method to create an empty object with a prototype

Yes, there is one that does exactly this. And you've already used it. It's called [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Your code is exactly equivalent to

```
var baseObj = {name: '', id: 0};
myUser = Object.create(Object.create(baseObj));
```

I'm not sure though whether you really intended this two-level inheritance or whether a single invocation would be enough.

Comment: Exactly! I should have thought of that. Thanks.